# Entity Framework RemoveRange does not CascadeDelete

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities People and FollowUps with a one to many relationship, with cascadedelete. As defined here (OnModelCreating) :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FollowUp>()
   .HasRequired(c => c.FollowUpPeople)
   .WithMany(p => p.FollowUps)
   .HasForeignKey(c => c.PersonID)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

My model entities are:

```
public class FollowUp {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public int PersonID { get; set; }
   public virtual People FollowUpPeople { get; set; }
}
```

And people:

```
public class People {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FollowUp> FollowUps { get; set; }
}
```

When deleting with people entities one by one cascade delete works just fine. ex:

```
context.People.Remove(person1);
context.People.Remove(person2);
context.SaveChanges();
```

when using RemoveRange i get an exception:

```
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or
more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a
relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the
foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined,
the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the
unrelated object must be deleted.
```

**Edit:** 
Here is how remove range is called:

```
List<People> peopleToAdd = new List<People>() { person1, person2 };
context.People.RemoveRange(peopleToAdd);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't anything else that's different between the Remove and RemoveRange situations? Looking at the implementation for these two methods in the [EntityFramework source](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Internal/Linq/InternalSet%60.cs) you can see that they both call the exact same `InternalContext.ObjectContext.DeleteObject` function.

Comment: Absolutely sure, the only thing i didn't add to my description was how RemoveRange was called. I'll edit now and add it

Answer (score -1):

RemoveRanges() does not support Cascade delete. All you can do is, just use foreach or for loop whatever suits you and just use remove().
For eg. In your case what you can do is,

```
foreach(People people in peopleToAdd){
  context.People.Remove(people);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You probably mean `RemoveRange()`. Either way, how can a LINQ method do anything to model configuration? Do you think the model cares *how* entities are deleted? You need a solid reference from official documentation to back such allegations.